# Postgresql's pg_dump and pg_restore across different major versions?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, pg-dump, pg-restore

Recently I came across a (maybe known problem) when Postgre's versions differ in major number (always upgrade, no downgrade), for example with field types.

In my case, there was very little conflicting data so I changed it by hand, but wanted to know more, in case I come across this problem again with more data.

In this concrete case (but can be extended to other possible problems in the future), I created the backup using only data inserts, as I had already the table structure saved.

The problem came when upgrading from 8.x to 9.x with the `money` type, I got errors because the inserts had a value something like

```
INSERT INTO foo(...) VALUES (...,'EUR300',...);
```

So postgres was refusing to insert that in 9.1

My idea, and what I tried is to convert that field to DECIMAL and redoing the dump, that worked, but in a future, is there another mechanism, like using newer pg_dump connecting to old database, instead of current one? (Did not tested this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When going etween different versions, you should always use the *new* version of `pg_dump`. Meaning when you go from 8.x to 9.1, you should use `pg_dump` version 9.1. It should normally take care of any conversions necessary.

Comment: Oh, you got me, I was about to try, but I had it already converted. MANY thanks :)