# Ideal version of pg_dump/pg_restore for Postgresql Migration

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

We are planning to migrate an on premises PostgreSQL 9.6 to Azure PostgresSQL 11. On our developer machines we have pg_dump/pg_restore v12.2

(Source-Postgresql v9.6) --> dump/restore v12.2 --> (Destination Azure Postgresql v11)

We have run into issues with the above setup.

Another developer has pg_dump/pg_restore version of 9.6 (Matches with source) and it smoothly migrates to Azure PostgreSql v11.

I have read on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485075/postgresqls-pg-dump-and-pg-restore-across-different-major-versions) (also other places) that ideally pg_dump/pg_restore should match with destination postgresql version.

**What should be the ideal version of pg_dump/pg_restore? Match source or destination version of PostgreSql?**

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html#UPGRADING-VIA-PGDUMPALL) "*It is recommended that you use the pg_dump and pg_dumpall programs from the **newer** version of PostgreSQL, to take advantage of enhancements that might have been made in these programs*"

Comment: Using the new version is the better choice. You should edit the question or start a new one and detail the problems and error messages you encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match the destination version. If you use version `X+1` of a database export tool, don't expect the resulting dump to work with the import tool of database version `X` - the newer export tool might emit stuff that was only introduced in the newer database version. On the other hand, there is no guarantee, that version `X` of the database export tool will play nicely with version `X-1` of the database. Chances are a lot better, though.

Try to use `pg_dump`/`pg_restore` in version 11 if your target version is 11.